# Null check ObservableCollection before querying it

Tags: c#, .net, linq, code-snippets

Is this code good enough:

```
if (MyCollection.Where(p => p.SomeID == idstring).Any())
{
   selectedval = MyCollection.Where(p => p.SomeID == idstring).FirstOrDefault().MyField;
}
```

My doubt is about the fact that I make the same query twice: first for null check and then to actually get data.

Maybe there is a better way to do this type of things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
var item = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SomeID == idstring);
if (item != null)
    selectval = item.MyField;
```

This avoids double querying the collection, which will certainly make a difference in big collections or if your collection performs a DB query.

Comment: I totally posted this 12 seconds before you did =D

Comment: I don't know what to say. Have you considered that we wrote at the same time? There are not many different answers to that question. Besides, I'm pretty sure mine was the only answer right after I posted it :)

Comment: Haha, I was just teasing you.  They were posted at about the same time.  Mine was the only answer I saw after I posted it, so probably some amount of lag going on.

Comment: Hehe. I think the folks liked mine better :D

Comment: Right... except it's exactly the same thing (Except you first had a needless call to `Where` before calling `FirstOrDefault`)... but like I said, I was joking.

Comment: And, of course I was joking too, because if the answers were basically the same, why on earth would anyone like mine better? :)

Comment: Ahhh yes... apparently I am a bit dense =D

Answer (score 3):

There is.  You can use the [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) method which takes a predicate and returns null if the item is not found.

```
var result = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SomeID == idstring);
if( result != null )
{
    // item was found
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Ed, I had to make this hard choice, so just followed the folks. Thank you very much, +1